# Does reporting a player for cheating also transmit the video footage?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

This game is riddled with cheaters at the moment it seems. Last night someone killed my teammate and I with a perfect headshot from very far away. I watched the deathcam and saw their crosshair jump across the screen directly onto my head as I walked past a window, so I pressed report.

I wondered if the footage is sent with the report to be reviewed, or if it is only for my own benefit and they still use a system of banning people based on a certain number of reports without directly investigating?

Comment: According to many Threads in net the deathcam is still bugged sometimes. Not sure if this was in your case, but i guess they get a lot of unjustified reports because of that and need a reliable, complex system to proof that Somebody is Cheating

Comment: Interesting, I haven't come across that. My example was pretty blatant, I've seen a lot of aimhacks in other games especially CS1.5 that we'd play on a LAN offline and deliberately load up as many cheats as possible to see who could win. I can understand that it can be ambiguous sometimes though.